# RawPrinterHelper and commands to Epson printer

Tags: c#, printing

I am very confused right now and I need someone explain why one thing isn't working yet another is.  I am using the [RawPrinterHelper](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/322091/how-to-send-raw-data-to-a-printer-by-using-visual-c-.net) to send commands to a receipt printer.  Right now trying to send the command 29,109 (cut paper)
 [found here for the TM-T88](http://keyhut.com/popopen4.htm).

I figured this should do the trick:

```
RawPrinterHelper.SendStringToPrinter(pName, ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(new byte[] { 29, 109 }));
```

It didn't work and doing some research I found this code;

```
string GS = Convert.ToString((char)29);
string ESC = Convert.ToString((char)27);
string COMMAND = "";
COMMAND = ESC + "@";
COMMAND += GS + "V" + (char)1;
RawPrinterHelper.SendStringToPrinter(pd.PrinterSettings.PrinterName, COMMAND);
```

This works perfectly.  Here is my confusion:

1. Why didn't my first code work?
2. Why is there so much more needed in the string?
3. Why is it using 29 instead of 109?
4. What is the "@" for?
5. What is the "V" for?

For example, I am really at a loss on how to send the command print logo: `28,112,1,0`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why didn't my first code work?

The documentation which you've linked to shows that 27, 109 is the sequence to send for the TM-T88. You code which isn't working, is sending 29, 109.
If you look at the code which is working, you'll see that 27 (ESC) is sent first. ESC is a typical message to a printer that commands are to follow rather than text to print.

> Why is there so much more needed in the string?

It's not so much needed, it's doing additional things, and using a different command to cut the paper as I'll show below.

> Why is it using 29 instead of 109?
>   What is the "@" for?
>   What is the "V" for?

Have a look at the commands here: https://reference.epson-biz.com/modules/ref_escpos/index.php?content_id=82

Full sequence of the working command is `ESC @ GS V 1`

`ESC @` is "Initialize printer"

`GS V` is described as "Select cut mode and cut paper". I assume the "1" after it is the mode being set, but as it has "cut paper" in the description that would by why it is cutting the paper.